# How to change the name of the attachement when sending the mail and attachement to a Sharepoint library

Tags: file-upload

Is it possible to change the name of the attachement when sending it to a Sharepoint library.

For instance, I have sent to a library in Sharepoint the file (attachment in a mail) 20130903.csv. When opening the library the file is saved as 20130903. I want to change that filename.

Answer (score 2):

Erik,

I will suggest you write a Workflow on the Library which runs on adding a new item on the Library and fixes the name!

Otherwise, if you are a developer.. You can also write Event Receiver on ItemAdding and set appropriate title.. Please look:

[Example: Creating a List Item Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
[Creating a SharePoint Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407274%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
[How to: Create an Event Receiver for a Specific List Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052.aspx)

Here is list of all ListTemplateId's
[SPListTemplateType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx)

Comment: @Erik if the post helped you, please mark as answer to close the question!